# Angular 7 : How to create simple pagination with routing for API data

Tags: angular, angular7

I ma new to Angular Like this

[image]

As it must change Route URL `http://my_project/products/page/3` whrn page change.

My API server give me data by paging like `http://apiserver/product/[limet]/[offset]` so I can get data by limit and offset

I tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination but this is not using routing

I search for it on google but I can not get any one. Please help thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you considered `ngx-pagination`, you should do the routing in the `pageChange` event yourself

`(pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"`

inside the component do the routing inside the `pageChanged` function

```
pageChanged(evt) {
    \\ Routing here
}
```

This [link](https://angular.io/guide/router) will help you with the routing process. `Router.navigate` is the point you should look for

Comment: but its not working if there is lost of data, like If i have 1000 data array from API server its loads all 1000 api data at one time after API call

Comment: You should get the pageIndex from the route after the routing finish, and you can define the pageSize, then you can assign it for the limit and offset on the API call, only display them

Comment: If you don't need the routing, just call the API and refresh the data right when the pageChanged function is called